# MVVM: Use different ViewModel Implementation depending on Use-case

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a fragment which is supposed to be reused in multiple use-cases, e.g. called `AddOrEditRecipeFragment`, this fragment can be used for creating or editing a recipe since it is the same UI no matter if you create or edit a recipe.

But I want to either use an `AddReceipeViewModel` or `EditRecipeViewModel` instance, depending on the use-case, which is identified by a FragmentArgument on the Fragment. Both `AddReceipeViewModel` and `EditRecipeViewModel` implement the same interface, so what I currently do is:

```
private val viewModel: MyViewModelInterface by lazy {
    val mode = // ... just get a flag from the arguments which indicates which mode we are in
    val vm: MyViewModelInterface = when(mode) {
        Mode.EDIT -> { val vm: EditRecipeViewModel by activityViewModel(); vm }
        Mode.ADD -> { val vm: AddRecipeViewModel by activityViewModel(); vm }
    vm
}
```

This feels very wrong since the fragment know needs to know all possible implementations of `MyViewModelInterface`. Does anyone know any better solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `factory` and pass the mode to the factory, leaving the logic to decide which viewmodel to instantiate to the `factory` so the fragment only depends on the interface.

In your fragment add this

```
private val factory = ViewModelFactory() // inject it instead if using DI
private val viewModel: MyVieModelInterface by activityViewModels {
    factory
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val mode = // get mode from arguments
    factory.mode = mode
}
```

with

```
abstract class MyVieModelInterface : ViewModel() /* rename as it's not an interface */ {

}

class ViewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    lateinit var mode: Mode

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(MyVieModelInterface::class.java)) {
        when (mode) {
            Mode.EDIT -> EditViewModel(/* stuff here */)
            Mode.ADD -> AddViewModel(/* stuff here */)
        }
    } else {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class [$modelClass]")
    }
}
```